# Error creating managed app registration with Intune Graph REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

The docs at 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/intune_mam_iosmanagedappregistration_create indicate that it should be possible to create an iOS managed app registration with a POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/managedAppRegistrations.  Any permutations on the documented behavior results in the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "No method match route template",
    "message": "No OData route exists that match template ~/singleton/navigation with http verb POST for request /MAMAdmin/MAMAdminFEService/deviceAppManagement/managedAppRegistrations.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "9338f5e5-bdb8-49f2-a887-362ddca6da97",
        "date": "2018-03-13T01:23:02"
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to indicate that there is a missing route for POST - has anyone been successful using this api to create managed app registrations?

I have tried several variations on input, including removing the odata type specifiers as mentioned in other posts here.  Below is a sample of a failing request that can be reproduced with graph explorer - note that I get the same error when using real values in an application attempting to integrate with the APIs:

```
 POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/managedAppRegistrations

 {
   "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.iosManagedAppRegistration",
   "lastSyncDateTime": "2017-01-01T00:02:49.3205976-08:00",
   "applicationVersion": "Application Version value",
   "managementSdkVersion": "Management Sdk Version value",
   "platformVersion": "Platform Version value",
   "deviceType": "Device Type value",
   "deviceTag": "Device Tag value",
   "deviceName": "Device Name value",
   "flaggedReasons": [
 "rootedDevice"
   ],
   "userId": "User Id value",
   "appIdentifier": {
 "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.iosMobileAppIdentifier",
 "bundleId": "Bundle Id value"
   },
   "version": "Version value"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a documentation error. ~/managedAppRegistrations is a read only collection. Those entities are created when a MAM enlightened app registers with Microsoft Intune.

Regards,
Alemeshet Alemu from MSFT